# Apollo's useQuery and updating a parent's prop with its result

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

I have a wrapping parent component that accepts some layout-related props, and a child component (representing a page) that needs to run a GraphQL query via Apollo, and update that parent's prop with the result (say the page title). The parent requiring props that I need to update is not a pattern I chose, but the implementation of a component I must use.

```js
App = () {
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState({});

  return (
    <Wrapper layout={layout: 'foo'}>
      <PageComponent setLayout={setLayout} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}


PageComponent = (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY); // Apollo's useQuery

  useEffect(() => {
    props.setPageParams({ title: data.lists[0].title });
  }, [data]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

  return (
    <p>component!</p>
  );
}
```

I've tried too many different approaches to write them all down here, but the results are one of two things: a **loop in the useEffect** (which I somewhat understand, I think passing `data` to `useEffect` is causing it to set the parent's props and re-render the child every time because it is an object and isn't been deeply compared), or the following:

```
Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`PageComponent`).
```

The latter happens while attempting a few approaches without `useEffect`, such as:

```
if(data && data.lists && awaitingPageLayout) {
  props.setLayout({ title: data.lists[0].title });
  awaitingPageLayout = false;
}
```

I have also tried to use useQuery's `onCompleted`, which I believe resulted in another loop.

Hoping for a push in the right direction, I'm out of ideas here. Appreciate your time!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't have the `useQuery` in the `App`?

Comment: @AdamJeliński I could, conceivably, but it would be ugly. The component represents a page and is rendered by a React Router `Route`, I wouldn't really want to bring all of my queries up to App when they really only have anything to do with the page components.